# Ошибка "invalid ELF header" при деплое проекта на VPS

Tags: linux, node.js

Использую Linux Ubuntu.  Проблема в том, что при запуске бэкенда пол на NodeJS получаю такую ошибку. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался установить отдельно, но проблема осталась.

Comment: что даст `rm -rf node_modules && npm i && node index.js`?

Comment: @nörbörnën я вообще ничего не понимаю. Пишет что-то с sequelize, наверное не может подключиться к базе данных. А я в душе не чаю как его добавить

Comment: то есть этой ошибки больше нет, после удаления node_modules и нормальной установки библиотек?

Comment: @nörbörnën получается так, а че теперь делать чтобы он запустился нормально?

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)

Comment: один вопрос - один ответ. думаю, причина вашей проблемы - вы закоммитили папку node_modules в своём проекте и перенесли на vps. папку node_modules носить с собой не нужно, библиотеки должны устанавливаться под платформу при деплое проекта

Comment: @nörbörnën Ну ладно. Спасибо. Ты мой герой